# htaccess dynamic folder rewriting

Tags: .htaccess

Here is the case I have and I am already wondering several days how to make it and it seems too complicated for me. I want to rewrite the following:

```
http://demo.myurl.com/proevent/event1 to http://demo.myurl.com/index.php?url=proevent&path=event1 

http://demo.myurl.com/proevent/admin to http://demo.myurl.com/admin - when folders exist under that location I want to have them loaded and not falling to /index.php
```

Now to say "proevent" and "event1" are completely dynamic!

Folders I know for sure are: admin, inc, photos that are existing, the rest are dynamic.

In all cases of redirection I'd like to know from the path what has been opened and give error msg or not.

Here is what I have so far:

skips the slash as people forget to put it and the folder doesn't exists

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.|/$)
    RewriteRule (.*) /$1/ [R=301,L]
if dir/file exists (doesn't really work)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ([^/]*)/(.*) /$2%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
```

also don't know when it does work as it may fall in previous cases

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(/?.*?)([^/]*)$ index.php?url=$1&path=$2 [L]
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([^/]*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -d
RewriteRule /(.*)$ /%1/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(/?.*?)$ index.php?url=$1&path=$2 [L]
```

will do it for you.

The first part checks to see if the full directory or the subdirectory is a file or not, and the second part redirects if that first part fails.

To be more clear

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Checks to see if this is a real file or dirctory to begin with.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([^/]*)$
```

Gets the final part of the URL as per your request.

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -d
```

These check is /(last part of the URL) is a file or a directory. This uses the backreference functionality of Rewrite. %1 reference the first chunk of the last RegEx in a RewriteCond.

```
RewriteRule /(.*)$ /%1/ [L]
```

If it's a directory, we rewrite

Otherwise, the next part is obvious and just rewrites to the get conditions you laid out.